# Find max frequency in each k sized subarray

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, sliding-window

Can be repetitive, but I couldn't find exact one.

This is the part of a problem involving Data Structure and Algotrithms:
Given an array of size n, find max frequency among the all elements in the each window/subarray of size k.

```
Ex1. a = {5,5,7,7,7,5} , k = 3
subarrays of size 3: 
{5,5,7} => freq[5] = 2, freq[7] = 1,  max frequency = 2 
{5,7,7} => freq[5] = 1, freq[7] = 2,  max frequency = 2
{7,7,7} => freq[7] = 3,               max frequency = 3
{7,7,5} => freq[5] = 1, freq[7] = 2,  max frequency = 2
answer array = {2,2,3,2}

Ex2: a = {5,5,6,5,5,6,6}, k = 5 , ans = {4, 3, 3}
Ex3  a = {1,2,3,4,5,6}  k = 2, ans = {1,1,1,1,1}
```

My goal is to solve this problem optimally in time complexity < O(N^2). Something like O(N * logN * logN). Not looking for O(N^2) Solution.

Constraints: N <= 10^5 , k <=N and a[i] <= 10^5

My approach:
I tried using an unordered map ( to store frequency of each subarray) and used multiset to resolve the problem of maximum after change in freq.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int check(vector<int> &nums, int k)
    {
        int n=nums.size();
        unordered_map<int,int> mp;
        multiset<int> st;
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {

            if( i >= k )
            {
                int idx_b = i-k;
                 auto itr2 = st.find(mp[nums[idx_b]]);
                if ( itr2!=st.end() ) st.erase(itr2);
                mp[nums[idx_b]]--;
                st.insert(mp[nums[idx_b]]);
            }

            int curr = mp[nums[i]]; 
            mp[nums[i]]++;

            auto itr1 = st.find(curr);
            if(itr1!=st.end())st.erase(itr1);
            st.insert(curr+1);

            auto mx = st.rbegin();
            if(i>=k-1 )
            {
                cout<<*mx<<endl;
            }
        }
        return 0;
        
    }



int main()
{
    vector<int> a { 5,5,6,6,6,7};
    check(a,3);
    
}
```

In my understanding the time complexity is O( n * 6 * log(n) ) log(n) for insert, find, and erase. But I am suspecting it to be wrong as the soln is failing as TLE.

Comment: @Ashutosh Rana by the  way one recommendation for you,you should also post  result what did you get

Comment: If time complexity is the goal, then design the algorithm and go from there. It's bad analysis to write the code and then try to figure out Big O.

Comment: Side note: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` [loads the gun](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4581301) and `using namespace std;` [takes the safety off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4581301). This combination makes it really easy to shoot yourself in the foot, so use this with a great deal of caution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of the following:

- A map with a value (from the array) as key, and the corresponding frequency it has in the current window as value
- A vector where the index represents a frequency, and the corresponding value represents the number of distinct values that have that frequency in the current window
- An integer that holds the maximum frequency held by a value in the current window

Then it is only a matter of keeping things updated as you extend the window to the right, and shrink it from the left:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>

std::vector<int> check(std::vector<int> &nums, int k) {
    int n = nums.size();
    std::unordered_map<int, int> frequencyOfValue;
    std::vector<int> countOfFrequency(n);
    int maxFrequency = 0;
    std::vector<int> result;

    // Get all distinct values and register their frequency (of 0)
    for (int value : nums) {
        frequencyOfValue[value] = 0;
    }
    countOfFrequency[0] = frequencyOfValue.size(); // Number of distinct values

    // Slide the window over the input vector
    for (int last = 0, start = 0; last < n; last++) {
        int value = nums[last];
        // Add this value to the data structure
        int frequency = frequencyOfValue[value];
        countOfFrequency[frequency]--;
        frequency++;
        countOfFrequency[frequency]++;
        frequencyOfValue[value] = frequency;
        if (frequency > maxFrequency) {
            maxFrequency++;
        }
        if (last >= k) { 
            // Remove the left side value from the data structure
            value = nums[start];
            frequency = frequencyOfValue[value];
            int count = --countOfFrequency[frequency];
            if (frequency == maxFrequency && count == 0) {
                // This was the only value having the max frequency
                maxFrequency--;
            }
            frequency--;
            countOfFrequency[frequency]++;
            frequencyOfValue[value] = frequency;
            start++;
        }
        if (last >= k - 1) {
            result.push_back(maxFrequency);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

NB: I wouldn't output the result with `cout` in the function itself. Leave that for the caller to do. Also [don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5459839) and [don't do `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5459839).

This has a time complexity of O().

Comment: I should be able to follow your code even though I don't know C++, but I can't figure out what you're doing. Nevermind that, I'm puzzled by your time complexity being only O(1). Suppose `k = 5`, the sliding window is currently `[4, 1, 4, 1, 3]`, and you have recorded a max frequency of `2` for it. I assume you are not enumerating the elements of each window to get the max frequency (O(n*k)), but are keeping track of an element that has the max frequency for the window...

Comment: ...That could be `4` or `1` but suppose it were `4`. Going to the next window `4` is dropped off. If `4` is also added on the right you know the max frequency for the new interval is also `2`, with `4` still having the max frequency. If, however, the element added to the interval were anything else would you not have to enumerate the interval to compute the max frequency? If the new element were `1`, for example, the max frequency would be 3. Doesn't that make the time-complexity O(n*k)?

Comment: @Cary, let's say the newly added value is 2, this code first adds it, and that doesn't change the max frequency. Then the left-hand 4 is dropped off (in the `if` block),  where `count` decreases from 2 to 1, indicating there is one more integer that has a frequency of 2, and so the inner `if` block doesn't execute (and max frequency remains 2). The rest of the code updates the structure to indicate that 4 occurs once now. Does that clarify it?

Comment: By "...where count decreases from 2 to 1,..." (which I assume refers to `4`'s count in the window) I reasoned that to conclude "...indicating there is one more integer that has a frequency of 2..." you would have to examine the frequency of the other `k-1` elements in the window (from the map/hash you maintain). Correct? If so, I concluded the time complexity is O(n*k). Bonehead that I am, I failed to realise that since `k` is constant it's still O(n).

Comment: It is not necessary to inspect the frequency of the other k-1 elements in the window. For each frequency, we know how many distinct values currently have that frequency in the window. If a value drops off, its frequency is decreased and so the count of the earlier frequency is decreased by one (and the new frequency gets an increment). So at all times we know how many distinct values in the window have a certain frequency. Since frequencies can only change by one unit at a time, we can always deduce what the greatest frequency is in the window, without iterating all its values again.

Comment: ...When a value with frequency 2 drops off, we can immediately know if there are still other values that have that frequency. If so, then the maximum frequency doesn't change. If there are none anymore, *and* this was the max frequency, then the maximum frequency decreases ***by one unit***, as we know for sure that the value that dropped off, now has *that* frequency in the window (which is one less than before).

Comment: Got it. Nice! I now understand your code too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a max heap and a counting map.

Put elements in the heap based on their count.

Adjust counts & update the heap when elements enter/leave the sliding window.

Running time is O(n log k) for n elements and a window of size k.

Ex2: a = {5,5,6,5,5,6,6}, k = 5 , ans = {4, 3, 3}

```
index map           comment
0:    {5=>1}
1:    {5=>2}
2:    {5=>2, 6=>1}
3:    {5=>3, 6=>1}
4:    {5=>4, 6=>1} # We've processed 5 elts; top of heap is 4 (from the 5)
5:    {5=>3, 6=>2} # We lose a 5 and gain a 6; top of heap is 3 (from the 5)
6:    {5=>2, 6=>3} # We lose another 5 and gain another 6; top of heap is 3 (from the 6)
```